# Group a Java List by multiple properties of its elements

Tags: java, list, duplicates, java-stream

I have a list of objects that contains duplicates based on multiple properties.  I want to convert this list in this way.  I think it's like a grouping by multiple properties

Example :

```
id name age job
1  Jane 25  job1
1  Jane 25  job2
1  Jane 25  job3
2  Adam 30  job4
2  Adam 30  job5
```

I want this list to turn like this:

```
1 Jane 25  (job1, job2, job3)
2 Adam 30  (job4, job5)
```

The list of jobs should be a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you expect is grouping the people by the id. It is convenient to use Java Stream API like *this*:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

// Create the class that represent the data type of each person
record Person(long id, String name, int age, String job) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return job;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> peopleList = List.of(
                new Person(1, "Jane", 25, "job1"),
                new Person(1, "Jane", 25, "job2"),
                new Person(1, "Jane", 25, "job3"),
                new Person(2, "Adam", 30, "job4"),
                new Person(2, "Adam", 30, "job5")
        );
        // Please use the API to solve the problem
        Map<Long, List<Person>> peopleMap = peopleList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::id));
        peopleMap.forEach((id, people) -> System.out.printf("id = %d, job = %s\n", id, people.toString()));
    }
}
```

The previous version regards `id` as the unique key, and we group people by `id` accordingly. Yet since we wish to include the 3 properties, we may redefine the class Person. Here is the *revised version*:

```java
record Keys(long id, String name, int age) {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Keys keys)) return false;
        return id() == keys.id();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id());
    }
}

class Person2 {
    private final Keys keys;
    private final String job;

    public Person2(long id, String name, int age, String job) {
        this.keys = new Keys(id, name, age);
        this.job = job;
    }

    public Keys getKeys() {
        return keys;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Person2 person2)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(keys, person2.keys);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(keys, job);
    }
}

class Answer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person2> peopleList = List.of(
                new Person2(1, "Jane", 25, "job1"),
                new Person2(1, "Jane", 25, "job2"),
                new Person2(1, "Jane", 25, "job3"),
                new Person2(2, "Adam", 30, "job4"),
                new Person2(2, "Adam", 30, "job5")
        );
        Map<Keys, List<Person2>> peopleMap = peopleList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person2::getKeys));
        peopleMap.forEach((keys, person2List) -> {
            System.out.printf("%d %s %d ", keys.id(), keys.name(), keys.age());
            System.out.println(person2List.stream().map(Person2::getJob).toList());
        });
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:
1 Jane 25 [job1, job2, job3]
2 Adam 30 [job4, job5].

Comment: If you are using Java 8 (which does not support `record`), then you can simply create a class _Person_ that describes each person.

Comment: But at the end I want to produce a new list that contains the three properties and a list of jobs

Comment: @Di_ I have revised my answer. Hope this one could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the *[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html)* class, and generate a *key* and *value* pair.

First, consider the following class, as a way to encapsulate your *object* with the *id*, *name*, *age*, and *job* values.

```java
class ValueA {
    int id, age;
    String name, job;

    public ValueA(int id, String name, int age, String job) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.job = job;
    }
}
```

And, additionally, since the *key* should be both the *name* and the *age*, we'll use another class.
Note, the *toString*, here, is for debugging, and is not required.

```java
class ValueB {
    String name;
    int age;

    public ValueB(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + age;
    }
}
```

You'll need to iterate on the *List* of *ValueA*, to populate the *Map*.
Furthermore, to identify the *key*, during iteration, we'll need an *inner for-loop*, on the *Map*.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ValueA> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ValueA(1, "Jane", 25, "job1"));
    list.add(new ValueA(1, "Jane", 25, "job2"));
    list.add(new ValueA(1, "Jane", 25, "job3"));
    list.add(new ValueA(2, "Adam", 30, "job4"));
    list.add(new ValueA(2, "Adam", 30, "job5"));

    Map<ValueB, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    ValueB key;
    List<String> value;
    for (ValueA valueA : list) {
        key = new ValueB(valueA.name, valueA.age);
        value = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<ValueB, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().name.equals(valueA.name) && entry.getKey().age == valueA.age) {
                key = entry.getKey();
                value = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        value.add(valueA.job);
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Output

```
{Jane 25=[job1, job2, job3], Adam 30=[job4, job5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following converts a list of your input items and converts it to a map where each key is the ID/name/age combination, and the values are that person's list of jobs.

```java
record PersonJob(int id, String name, int age, String job) {}
record Person(int id, String name, int age) {
    Person(PersonJob s) {
        this(s.id(), s.name(), s.age());
    }
}

List<PersonJob> list = List.of(
        new PersonJob(1, "Jane", 25, "job1"),
        new PersonJob(1, "Jane", 25, "job2"),
        new PersonJob(1, "Jane", 25, "job3"),
        new PersonJob(2, "Adam", 30, "job4"),
        new PersonJob(2, "Adam", 30, "job5")
);

Map<Person, List<String>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Person::new,
                Collectors.mapping(PersonJob::job, Collectors.toList())));
```

This groups all items based on unique `id`/`name`/`age` combination, mapping each those to a `List` of all jobs corresponding to that combination.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sample set of data, it appears that `name` and `age` are based on the `id`.  In other words, given two values with the same `id`, the `name` and `age` will be the same.  Assuming this is correct, the following converts a list of your input items and converts it to a list of items containing the `id`, `name`, `age`, and a list of all jobs.

```java
record PersonJob(int id, String name, int age, String job) {}
record PersonJobs(int id, String name, int age, List<String> jobs) {
    PersonJobs(List<PersonJob> l) {
        this(l.getFirst().id(), l.getFirst().name(), l.getFirst().age(),
                l.stream().map(PersonJob::job).toList());
    }
}

List<PersonJob> list = List.of(
        new PersonJob(1, "Jane", 25, "job1"),
        new PersonJob(1, "Jane", 25, "job2"),
        new PersonJob(1, "Jane", 25, "job3"),
        new PersonJob(2, "Adam", 30, "job4"),
        new PersonJob(2, "Adam", 30, "job5")
);

Map<Integer, PersonJobs> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                PersonJob::id,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), PersonJobs::new)));
List<PersonJobs> resultList = List.copyOf(map.values());
```

This groups the items by `id`, then for each `id` and list of values with that ID, creates a new object containing the `id`, `name`, `age`, and the jobs corresponding to that ID.